# App rejected due to watchdog timer timeout by apple But didFinishLaunching does not take too long

Tags: ios, app-store, watchdog

I know there are tons of questions about the same issue but most of the answer relates to blocking the UI and main thread for some calls made in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

I tried to run timer instrument for my application, and debug my code(device & simulators). On the first launch of the application, it takes around 11 seconds to pass splash screen, but when I debug my code, it takes around 8-9 seconds even before executing the first line of code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

So it seems like my appDelegateMethods at total takes around 2-3 seconds allow app becoming responsive, which seems kind of fair.

Also after the first launch when I try to run my app with or without timer instruments, it takes around 4-5 seconds to become active.

So my question is: Why my app takes around 8-9 seconds on first launch to get to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method?

I also don't have anything in `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Do you have any ideas? Or do I miss somethings here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you may have problems with dynamic libraries load time. You may check this problem by adding environment variable `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` to your scheme and checking your console output after launch.

[image: settings]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it seems like all the libraries take around 1,5 seconds, and 0,75 seconds on second launch:

Total pre-main time: 1.5 seconds (100.0%)
         dylib loading time: 466.14 milliseconds (29.8%)
        rebase/binding time: 105.94 milliseconds (6.7%)
            ObjC setup time: 119.77 milliseconds (7.6%)
           initializer time: 869.70 milliseconds (55.6%)
           slowest intializers :
             libSystem.B.dylib :  19.81 milliseconds (1.2%)
          and three more libraries (sorry comment limit)

Comment: Upon further research I couldn't find why there was delay in first launch, and just submited another build without changing anything and now its accepted :D. But thank you, for suggesting DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS, it allowed me to do further research and learn more about what happens before app launches.

Comment: @emrepun Glad you have passed review :)